# How do I install `openvt` in Debian Jessie?

Tags: debian

Following [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/584931/howto-start-an-interactive-script-at-ubuntu-startup), I tried to use the command line tool `openvt` on my debian jessie install. However it seems to not be available.

Some googling suggests that the openvt command is included in the `console-tools` package. However trying to install console-tools just results in the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install console-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package console-tools is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'console-tools' has no installation candidate
```

It seems like console-tools is no longer available? It's also not in the [allpackages list](https://packages.debian.org/stable/allpackages).

So my questions are:

- is there another package that can be used to install openvt?
- is there an alternative to openvt?
- how do I find out why the package is no longer availbable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`openvt` is in the [`kbd`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/kbd) package (you can find that out using `apt-file search openvt`). There isn’t really an alternative to `openvt`, although you can manage VTs with systemd.

To find out why the package is no longer available, look for it in the [package tracker](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/console-tools); this will point you to the [removal bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=671342) which usually has the relevant details.